# How to know WCF service availability?

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to know whether the WCF service is available or not before making a service call.
What could be the best way?

How about using this:

```
bool isServiceUp = true;
try
{
   string address = "http://localhost/MyService.svc?wsdl";

 MetadataExchangeClient mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(new Uri(address), MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet);
   MetadataSet metadata = mexClient.GetMetadata();
// if service down I get the exception
}
   catch (Exception ex)
{
    isServiceUp = false;
}
```

**My service is using net tcp binding.**

can i use it for net tcp binding?

**EDIT:** Thanks JaredPar. Suppose my first call gets succeeded and while second call the server is down. So before making the service call i check the state of the proxy which is in the OPEN state and hence i make the service call which eventually gets time out. I haven't set any open or close time out so by default it takes 1 minute and the call gets caught in the Fault event handler of the service in which i dispose the proxy. But by that time UI hangs , what shd i do?

Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of test is simply not possible.  There is no way to reliably detect if a given WCF, or really any networking call, will succeed before you attempt it.  There are simply too many variables which are outside your control.

- The physical network
- The power source on the machine where WCF is running
- The actual WCF program
- The stability of the hard drive on the computer where your code or the WCF code is running

Any of these can be terminated / changed at any point in time.  Hence it's impossible to predict whether or not a given call will succeed.

The best way to approach this problem is simply make the call add the code to handle the cases where it does fail.

Comment: ServiceContract with ***Ping*** method and test availability for `database connection, active directory, FileSystem, Email, Ftp, SFtp, SMS API`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below, it works for me. And the ServiceController class live in the 'System.ServiceProces' namespace.

```
try
{
    ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Service Name", "Computer's IP Address");
    Console.WriteLine("The service status is currently set to {0}",
        sc.Status.ToString());

    if ((sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) ||
        (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service is Stopped, Ending the application...");
        Console.Read();
        EndApplication();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service is Started...");
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred trying to access the Server service...");
    Console.Read();
    EndApplication();
}
```